# UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native Library jniopencv_core.dll already loaded in another classloader

Tags: tomcat, opencv, tomcat7, javacv, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I'm been trying to deployed a JavaCV app on tomcat, but I have not success and it after first run return me UnsatisfiedLinkError.

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet servlets.ImageRecognize threw exception
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:999)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:565)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

root cause

java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native Library D:\javacv-bin\windows-x86_64\jniopencv_core.dll already loaded in another classloader
    java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary1(ClassLoader.java:1905)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1864)
    java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1854)
    java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:845)
    java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1084)
    com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.loadLibrary(Loader.java:593)
    com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:489)
    com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:431)
    com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.<clinit>(opencv_core.java:136)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was searching for a permanent solution to this when I found you experiencing the same problem.

The temporary fix to this is to restart Apache Server (and not just let the module context automatically reload) each time you make changes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are loading openCV dependency twice. Load once.